Emulating Android Browser Properties Using MITMProxy and Undetected-Driver: Inconsistent Results
I'm working on a project that involves disguising a browser as an Android device to pass a web-based fingerprinting test provided by CreepJS. The goal is to change various browser properties such as navigator, userAgent, and others to mimic an Android device. I'm using MITMProxy to intercept and modify web traffic and undetected-chromedriver (referred to as uc) for browser automation.
My Setup
Here are the Android device properties I want to emulate:
Resolution: 384 x 854
GPU: Adreno (TM) 650
Network: 4G, WiFi
Navigator:
    userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
    platform: Android
    hardwareConcurrency: 8
    deviceMemory: 8
    vendor: Google
    appVersion: "5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
    languages: ['en-US', 'en']
    timezone: America/New_York
    User Agent Data:
        Chrome 125
        Android 12.0.0
        SM-G986u

Current Approach
I'm using the following MITMProxy script to inject a custom JavaScript snippet that emulates these properties:
import mitmproxy.http
import logging

from mitmproxy import ctx

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

device_emulation_script = """
(function() {
    if (self.__injected_worker_emulator) return;
    self.__injected_worker_emulator = true;

    console.log('Injecting worker script to emulate device properties and intercept fetch requests');

    const deviceModel = {
        platform: 'Android',
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; SM-A205U) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.6367.159 Mobile Safari/537.36',
        hardwareConcurrency: 8,
        deviceMemory: 8,
        vendor: 'Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd',
        language: 'en-US',
        languages: ['en-US', 'en'],
        timezone: 'America/New_York'
    };

    // Create a proxy to emulate navigator properties
    const navigatorProxy = new Proxy(navigator, {
        get(target, property) {
            if (property in deviceModel) {
                return deviceModel[property];
            }
            return property in target ? target[property] : undefined;
        }
    });

    // Replace the original navigator with the proxy
    Object.defineProperty(self, 'navigator', {
        get: function() {
            return navigatorProxy;
        }
    });

    // Emulate timezone by wrapping Date functions
    const originalDate = Date;
    self.Date = class extends originalDate {
        constructor(...args) {
            if (args.length === 0) {
                const dateInstance = new originalDate();
                const localOffset = dateInstance.getTimezoneOffset();
                const emulatedOffset = getEmulatedTimezoneOffset();
                return new originalDate(dateInstance.getTime() + (emulatedOffset - localOffset) * 60000);
            }
            return new originalDate(...args);
        }

        static now() {
            const now = originalDate.now();
            const localOffset = new originalDate().getTimezoneOffset();
            const emulatedOffset = getEmulatedTimezoneOffset();
            return now + (emulatedOffset - localOffset) * 60000;
        }

        getTimezoneOffset() {
            return getEmulatedTimezoneOffset();
        }
    };

    function getEmulatedTimezoneOffset() {
        // Offset in minutes for emulated timezone 'America/New_York'
        return -5 * 60; // for 'America/New_York'
    }

    // Intercept fetch and log requests
    const originalFetch = fetch;
    self.fetch = async function(...args) {
        console.log('Intercepted fetch:', args);
        const response = await originalFetch(...args);
        // Modify response here if needed
        return response;
    };

    // Emulate Worker creation
    const originalWorker = Worker;
    self.Worker = class extends originalWorker {
        constructor(scriptURL, options) {
            console.log('Creating worker with emulated properties:', scriptURL);
            super(scriptURL, options);
        }
    };

    // Emulate SharedWorker creation
    const originalSharedWorker = SharedWorker;
    self.SharedWorker = class extends originalSharedWorker {
        constructor(scriptURL, name) {
            console.log('Creating shared worker with emulated properties:', scriptURL);
            super(scriptURL, name);
        }
    };

    // Emulate ServiceWorker registration
    const originalRegister = navigator.serviceWorker.register;
    navigator.serviceWorker.register = async function(scriptURL, options) {
        console.log('Registering service worker with emulated properties:', scriptURL);
        return await originalRegister.call(this, scriptURL, options);
    };
})();

"""

class WorkerEmulator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("worker-emulator")

    def response(self, flow: mitmproxy.http.HTTPFlow):
        # Intercept and modify worker scripts
        if flow.request.url.endswith(".js"):
            content_type = flow.response.headers.get("Content-Type", "")
            if "javascript" in content_type or "application/x-javascript" in content_type:
                self.logger.info(f"Intercepting script: {flow.request.url}")
                content = flow.response.content.decode("utf-8")
                # Inject the emulation script into the worker script
                modified_content = self.inject_emulation_script(content)
                flow.response.content = modified_content.encode("utf-8")
                self.logger.info(f"Modified script: {flow.request.url}")

    def inject_emulation_script(self, original_script):
        # Simple approach: prepend emulation script
        return f"{device_emulation_script}\n{original_script}"

addons = [
    WorkerEmulator()
]

Issues Encountered

Inconsistent Navigator Properties: Despite injecting the script,
properties like navigator.platform sometimes return undefined or do
not reflect the emulated values consistently.
Worker Blocking: Some tests on the CreepJS site indicate that
Workers are blocked or not functioning correctly, even though the
script attempts to emulate Worker behavior.
Incomplete Emulation: Tests reveal that certain features, such as
WebGL and other navigator properties, are not fully emulated or
detected as unknown.

Automation Setup
Here's my uc (nodriver) setup:
import asyncio
import os
import nodriver as uc


async def main():

    browser = await uc.start(
        headless=False,
        browser_args=[
            "--incognito",
            "--disk-cache-size=0"
            # f"--https-certificate={cer}",
            "--touch-events"
            "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
            "--disable-gpu",
            "--window-size=360,800",
            "--disable-background-networking",
            "--disable-background-timer-throttling",
            "--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows",
            "--disable-breakpad",
            "--disable-client-side-phishing-detection",
            "--disable-component-update",
            "--disable-default-apps",
            "--disable-domain-reliability",
            "--disable-features=AudioServiceOutOfProcess",
            "--disable-hang-monitor",
            "--disable-ipc-flooding-protection",
            "--disable-popup-blocking",
            "--disable-prompt-on-repost",
            "--disable-renderer-backgrounding",
            "--disable-sync",
            "--force-color-profile=srgb",
            "--metrics-recording-only",
            "--no-first-run",
            "--safebrowsing-disable-auto-update",
            "--password-store=basic",
            "--use-mock-keychain",
            "--lang=en-US",
            "--platform-override='Android'",
            "--proxy-server=http://127.0.0.1:8080"  # Proxy setting for mitmproxy
        ]
    )

    # Navigate to the actual target URL
    await browser.get('https://abrahamjuliot.github.io/creepjs/')

    print("Listening for responses. Press Ctrl+C to stop.")
    try:
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(222)  # Keep the script running
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("BrowserController: Starting the app")
    asyncio.run(main())
    print("BrowserController: App finished")

What I'm Looking For

Better Methodology: Are there more reliable methods to ensure
navigator and worker properties are correctly emulated?
Alternative Approaches: Should I consider a different approach or
tools for emulating Android device properties?
Mitigation of Issues: How can I address the inconsistencies and
worker blocking effectively?

Any insights or advice on improving this setup would be greatly appreciated!
